# Argparse: How to switch from default parser to a different subparser when a certain optional argument is given?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a certain script that is normally called with 2 positional arguments and bunch of optional arguments.

```
script.py <file1> <file2>
```

I want to add another subparser which should be called when I pass an optional argument.

```
script.py -file_list <files.list>
```

Basically, what I require is that when `-file_list` is passed, the parser shouldn't look for `file1` and `file2`. I do not want the default case to require another option to invoke it (since the default case is already in use and thus I do not want to break it).

I tried keeping the default parser as is and creating subparser for `-file_list`. But the parser still expects the positional arguments `file1` and `file2`.

Sample code (this doesn't work as I want it to):

```py
args = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#default arguments
args.add_argument("file1", type=str)
args.add_argument("file2", type=str)

#subparser for file_list
file_list_sp = args.add_subparsers()
file_list_parser = file_list_sp.ad_parser("-file_list")
file_list_parser.add_argument("file_list")

all_args = args.parse_args()
```

Maybe I need to create a seperate subparser for the default case; but all subparsers seem to need an extra command to invoke them. I want default case to be invoked automatically whenever -file_list is not passed

Comment: `-fil_list` is not a valid subparser name.  When using subparsers it is hard to have a 'default' case.  You need to define a subparser for each alternative.  Practice with the documented style before trying to to do something novel.

Comment: @hpaulj It *could* be, if you change the prefix character. But you are right, it's better to stick with the established conventions than to try something different. (I suspect the ability to change the prefix character is intended to allow an existing interface to be duplicated, not to encourage "innovation" in command-line interfaces.)

Comment: @chepner Your suspicion is indeed correct. The form `script.py <file1> <file2>` already exists. I need to add a new option where the user is able to pass a a file which just has list of file pairs. Thus the original command should continue working as is.

Comment: I don't think there's any good `argparse`-based solution for this, short of reimplementing most of the argument processing manually. Subcommands and  ordinary top-level positional arguments don't really play well together. You might be able to define a custom action for a `-file_list` option, or post-process the parsed args, but `argparse` (out of the box) can't handle the logic you want to implement.

Comment: The 2 positionals are still required.  `subparsers` is another positional.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution like this from the `argparse` module you are probably out of luck.

Comment: @chepner, I got a mutually_exclusive_group to work (more or less), but using a undocumented detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in passing other optionals, so I assume there's good incentive to keep `argparse`.  Assuming there aren't other positionals, you could try:

```
In [23]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [24]: parser.add_argument('--other'); # other optionals
In [25]: parser.add_argument('--filelist');   
In [26]: parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*');
```

This accepts the '--filelist', without requiring the positional files, (with a resulting empty list):

```
In [27]: parser.parse_args('--filelist alist'.split())
Out[27]: Namespace(other=None, filelist='alist', files=[])
```

Other the files - but restricting that list to 2 requires your own testing after parsing:

```
In [28]: parser.parse_args('file1 file2'.split())
Out[28]: Namespace(other=None, filelist=None, files=['file1', 'file2'])
```

But it also accepts both forms.  Again your own post parsing code will have to sort out the conflicting message:

```
In [29]: parser.parse_args('file1 file2 --filelist xxx'.split())
Out[29]: Namespace(other=None, filelist='xxx', files=['file1', 'file2'])
```

And you have to deal with the case where neither is provided:

```
In [30]: parser.parse_args('--other foobar'.split())
Out[30]: Namespace(other='foobar', filelist=None, files=[])
```

The help:

```
In [32]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--other OTHER] [--filelist FILELIST]
                             [files ...]

positional arguments:
  files

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --other OTHER
  --filelist FILELIST
```

So what I've created accepts both forms of input, but does not constrain them.

I tried using a mutually_exclusive_group, but that only works with `nargs='?'`.  I thought at one time `nargs='*'` worked in a group, but either my memory is wrong, or there was a patch that changed things.  A positional in a m-x-group has to have 'required=False' value.

A `subparsers` is actually a special kind of `positional`.  So if you created parser with usage  'prog file1 file2 {cmd1, cmd2}' it would still expect the 2 file names before checking on the third string.  All `positionals`, including `subparsers` are handled by position, not value.   A flagged argument (`optional`) can occur in any order, but does not override the `positionals`.

And if you define the `subparsers` first, then the first positional has to be one of those commands.  `subparsers` are not required (by default), but that doesn't change the handling of other positionals.

### working mutually exclusive group

`nargs='*'` does work if we also specify a `default`.  This is a undocumented detail.  I forgot about it until I looked at the code (specifically the  `_get_positional_kwargs` method).  A `*` is marked as `required` unless it's given a `default`.  It's been discussed in one or more bug/issue some time ago.

So can make positional list and '--file_list' mutually exclusive

```
In [71]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [72]: parser.add_argument('--other'); # other optionals
In [73]: group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
In [74]: group.add_argument('--file_list');
In [75]: group.add_argument('files', nargs='*', default=[]);
```

Good cases:

```
In [76]: parser.parse_args('--other foobar file1 file2'.split())
Out[76]: Namespace(other='foobar', file_list=None, files=['file1', 'file2'])

In [77]: parser.parse_args('--other foobar --file_list file3'.split())
Out[77]: Namespace(other='foobar', file_list='file3', files=[])
```

If both are used:

```
In [78]: parser.parse_args('--other foobar --file_list file3 file1 file2'.split())
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--other OTHER] [--file_list FILE_LIST]
                             [files ...]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: argument files: not allowed with argument --file_list
```

And if neither is provided:

```
In [79]: parser.parse_args('--other foobar'.split())
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--other OTHER] [--file_list FILE_LIST]
                             [files ...]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: one of the arguments --file_list files is required
```

Usage now looks like:

```
In [81]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--other OTHER] [--file_list FILE_LIST]
                             [files ...]
```

It still doesn't control the number of files - except there must be atleast one.

Comment: I did something similar. I kept file1 & file2 option, but made them '?'. I check manually for their existence now, in case --filelist option is not provided. That was good enough for my case.